# Mapping entities to dynamic tablename

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I want to create a hibernate mapping to a data-source with dynamic tablenames. The tables reflect datasets extracted from another source by a legacy tool, and the tablename itself carries meta-information about the data in the table. The tablename would change for every request.

Is it possible to map this in hibernate? I'm thinking some temporary interceptor thing to change the table name, but cant really wrap my head around the best way to do this.

---

edited 12/07/12

..and i probably should have mentioned that readonly access is all i need. The tables represents "report" data, hence should never be changed.

Comment: Care to explain better how the table name is determined? Is it some sort of sharding, like, "records for Johns goes to table PeopleJohn", or is it really new tables for each request?

Comment: It's really new tables for each request. The tablename consists of a timestamp and an id, e.g. 201206081405_86223471.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic table names are not so easy with hibernate because the sessionfactory is immutable. You would need to Build up a new sessionfactory everytime. Depending on the use case i see several options:

- **readonly:** use an sqlquery with fixed column alias and use AliasToBean
- r**ead write:** use xml mapping templates and build up a new sessionfactory on every request (probably slow)
- **if possible tablenames are known at startuptime:** generate a mapping for each tablename and use entityname to differenciate which one to use at runtime

Comment: Ok, didn't know about AliasToBean. Looks promising. I would rather avoid having to build a new SessionFactory every time, and there's no way to know the tables at startup, as they are generated in parallel..